# MySQL - Hash Partition not working

Tags: mysql, sql, select, partitioning

I am using **MySQL 5.6** Server. I had created a table with **HASH partitiong** but some how I am unable to use specific partitions in my query.

**Table Structure**

```
CREATE TABLE `testtable` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `purchased` DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `ìd` (`id`),
  KEY `Purchased` (`purchased`)
) ENGINE=INNODB 
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE ( YEAR(purchased))
SUBPARTITION BY HASH ( dayofyear(purchased))
SUBPARTITIONS 366
(PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (2015) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2016) ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

**My Query**

```
EXPLAIN PARTITIONS
SELECT *
FROM testtable
WHERE purchased BETWEEN '2014-12-29' AND '2014-12-31';
```

Check [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8cb5/2) Page

My EXPLAIN plan tells me that server is using all partitions instead of specific partitions.

How can I write a query so that server scans specific partitions?
And also want to know what is the problem with my current query and why it is not working?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Your query is looking at 366 subpartitions of his first partition.

Comment: @wchiquito I know that but my problem is that the query should use partition 363,364,365

Answer (score 0):

True.  HASH partitioning is essentially useless.

Other things to note...

Having more than about 50 partitions leads to certain inefficiencies.

If you will be purging "old" rows, then consider BY RANGE and have a month in each partition.  Then do the purging via DROP PARTITION.  More details, including sample code: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint